# I am trying to convert a variable into date by using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to convert `var bc` into date by using momentjs. My expected output is 2019-08-08 07:44:15, but actual output is 2609-10-28 03:17:54.

I am getting this value from external system and data type is `string`

```js
var bc = 20190808074415;
var now = moment(bc).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
alert(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse your input, since it is not in ISO 8601 nor RFC 2822 recognized format.

```js
var bc = 20190808074415;
var now = moment(bc, 'YYYYMMDDHHmmss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```